# Clean way to map an array in node.js or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

Let's say I have a function and an array. I want to modify the array by applying the function to each entry in the array. The function does NOT modify the value directly; it returns a new value.

In pseudo-code,

```
for (entry in array) {
    entry = function(entry);
}
```

There are a couple ways to do this that occurred to me:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = fn(i);
}
```

Or, since I am using node.js and have underscore built in:

```
arr = _.map(arr, fn);
```

But this both seem a little clunky. The standard "for" block feels overly verbose, and the _.map function re-assigns the entire array so feels inefficient.

How would you do this?

Yes, I am aware I'm overthinking this :)

Comment: Just use the underscore-function until you are certain that it is a performance issue. It is very readable and clean, so unless it is actually an issue, your "feeling of inefficiency" shouldn't stop you from moving on to more pressing issues :)

Comment: Completely true! I'm just curious, nonetheless.

Answer (score 25):

The [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```
var arr = arr.map(fn);
```

`_.map()` is probably implemented in the same way.

Comment: If you're using Node.js you know what JS Interpreter you are using, thus you know that things from ECMAScript5 are implemented... which includes Array#map :)